# pyside change color of QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyside, qtreewidgetitem

How can I change the color of a QTreeWidgetItem in pyside? I want some to be red and some to be blue. I've tried various things and i haven't found a working solution yet. Hope someone can help.
Thanks

[image]

```
# Modules
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg

# widget
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        # formatting
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")

        # widgets
        self.itemList = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.itemList.setItemsExpandable(True)
        self.itemList.setAnimated(True)
        self.itemList.setItemsExpandable(True)
        self.itemList.setColumnCount(2)
        self.itemList.setHeaderLabels(['', ''])

        # add items
        item0 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.itemList, ['testing'])
        item1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.itemList, ['testing'])

        # add children
        for i in xrange(0,4):
            item00 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item0, ["Name"])

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.itemList)
        self.show()

# Main
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
item1.setForeground(0,QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("red")))
```

Comment: For PyQt5, the syntax is similar: `item1.setForeground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("red")))`.  (I found this searching for help with PyQt5, so maybe this comment can help future me)